# Calculate integral $\int^{+\infty}_0 \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(x^2+\frac{1}{2})^2} dx$?

Tags: probability, integration

I've posted a similar integral earlier, in which the Goodwin-Staton Integral is involved, making the integral unsolvable. Now I make a little modification to make it solvable and give my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

$$\begin{array}\ \int^{+\infty}_0 \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(x^2+\frac{1}{2})^2} dx &= 2\bigg[\int^{+\infty}_0 \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2+\frac{1}{2}} dx - \int^{+\infty}_0 \frac{x^2e^{-x^2}}{(x^2+\frac{1}{2})^2} dx\bigg]\\ &= 2\bigg[\int^{+\infty}_0 \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2+\frac{1}{2}} dx + \frac{1}{2}\int^{+\infty}_0xe^{-x^2}d(\frac{1}{x^2+\frac{1}{2}})\bigg]\\ &= 2\bigg[\int^{+\infty}_0 \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2+\frac{1}{2}} dx - \frac{1}{2}\int^{+\infty}_0\frac{1-2x^2}{x^2+\frac{1}{2}}e^{-x^2}dx\bigg]\\ &= 2\int^{+\infty}_0e^{-x^2}dx\\ &= \sqrt{\pi} \end{array}$$

Answer (score 2):

Integrate by parts directly

$$\begin{array}\ 
\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(x^2+\frac{1}{2})^2} dx 
&= \int^{\infty}_0 \frac{e^{-x^2}}x d\left( \frac{x^2}{x^2+\frac{1}{2}} \right)=
 2\int^{\infty}_0e^{-x^2}dx= \sqrt{\pi} \end{array}$$

Comment: concise answer :-)+ 1

Answer (score 0):

$$\displaystyle{\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{{e^{ - {x^2}}}}}{{{{\left( {{x^2} + 1/2} \right)}^2}}}dx}  = \mathop  = \limits^{x = \sqrt y }  = \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{{e^{ - y}}}}{{\sqrt y {{\left( {y + 1/2} \right)}^2}}}dy} \mathop  = \limits^{\left\lfloor * \right\rfloor } \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{{e^{ - y}}}}{{\sqrt y }}\left( {\int\limits_0^\infty  {x{e^{ - \left( {y + 1/2} \right)x}}dx} } \right)dy}  = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ = \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^\infty  {x{e^{ - x/2}}\left( {\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{1}{{\sqrt y }}{e^{ - \left( {x + 1} \right)y}}dy} } \right)dx} \mathop  = \limits^{\left\lfloor {**} \right\rfloor } \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^\infty  {x{e^{ - x/2}}\frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{{\sqrt {x + 1} }}dx}  = \frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{2}\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{x}{{\sqrt {x + 1} }}{e^{ - x/2}}dx}  = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ = \mathop  = \limits^{x + 1 = {y^2}}  = \sqrt \pi  \sqrt e \int\limits_1^\infty  {\left( {{y^2} - 1} \right){e^{ - {y^2}/2}}dy}  = \mathop  = \limits^{y = x\sqrt 2 }  = \sqrt {2\pi } \sqrt e \int\limits_{1/\sqrt 2 }^\infty  {\left( {2{x^2} - 1} \right){e^{ - {x^2}}}dx}  = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ = 2\sqrt {2\pi } \sqrt e \int\limits_{1/\sqrt 2 }^\infty  {{x^2}{e^{ - {x^2}}}dx}  - \sqrt {2\pi } \sqrt e \int\limits_{1/\sqrt 2 }^\infty  {{e^{ - {x^2}}}dx}  =  - \sqrt {2\pi } \sqrt e \int\limits_{1/\sqrt 2 }^\infty  {x{{\left( {{e^{ - {x^2}}}} \right)}^\prime }dx}  - \sqrt {2\pi } \sqrt e \int\limits_{1/\sqrt 2 }^\infty  {{e^{ - {x^2}}}dx}  = }$$

$$\displaystyle{ =  - \sqrt {2\pi } \sqrt e \left( { - \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2e} }} - \int\limits_{1/\sqrt 2 }^\infty  {{e^{ - {x^2}}}dx} } \right) - \sqrt {2\pi } \sqrt e \int\limits_{1/\sqrt 2 }^\infty  {{e^{ - {x^2}}}dx}  = \sqrt \pi  }$$

It also applies $$\displaystyle{\left\lfloor * \right\rfloor :{\text{ }}\int\limits_0^\infty  {x  {e^{ - a  x}}dx}  = \frac{1}{{{a^2}}}}$$ $$\displaystyle{\left\lfloor {**} \right\rfloor :{\text{ }}\int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{1}{{\sqrt x }}{e^{ - a x}}dx}  = \frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{{\sqrt a }}}$$ in general $$\displaystyle{\int\limits_0^\infty  {{x^y} {e^{ - a x}}dx}  = \frac{{\Gamma \left( {y + 1} \right)}}{{{a^{y + 1}}}}}.$$